How can I make a vector of the products of the elements $(a_0b_0,a_0b_1,a_1b_0,a_1b_1)$ from the vectors $(a_0,a_1)$, $(b_0,b_1)$?
Given the vectors
$$\bar{a}=\left(\begin{array}\\a_0\\a_1\end{array}\right), \hspace{5pt} \bar{b}=\left(\begin{array}\\b_0\\b_1\end{array}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^2,$$
is there any way to get the following vector using matrix operations?
$$
\left(\begin{array}\\a_0b_0\\a_0b_1\\a_1b_0\\a_1b_1\end{array}\right)
$$
My goal is to use this in code (Python, numpy), so solutions for n-dimensional vectors are welcome. The best I've got so far is
$$
\left(\begin{array}\\a_0b_0\\a_0b_1\\a_1b_0\\a_1b_1\end{array}\right) =
\left(\begin{array}\\a_0 & 0\\0 & a_0\\a_1 & 0\\0 & a_1\end{array}\right) 
\left(\begin{array}\\b_0\\b_1\end{array}\right) =
\left(\begin{array}\\a_0I\\a_1I\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}\\b_0\\b_1\end{array}\right)
$$
but I wasn't able to simplify it any more. The last equality uses some improper notation that I think I could make work in Python, but it would be nice to have a pure linear algebra solution if that's possible. Thanks in advance.

What's the problem with just defining $(a_0b_0,a_0b_1,a_1b_0,a_1b_1)$ in python directly?

You could use the dyadic product or outer product $\otimes$ and then $a \otimes b = ab^T$ gives you a $2 \times 2$ matrix whose components are what you're looking for (so you can flatten the matrix), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics

@Lorago It absolutely works for this case, but I really need a scalable solution that works for any length of $\bar a$ and $\bar b$.

You can do
$$\begin{pmatrix}a_0\\ a_1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}b_0&b_1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a_0b_0&a_0b_1\\a_1b_0&a_1b_1\end{pmatrix}$$
and then maybe list the rows together into one vector.
Hope this helps. :)
